# Falha na atribuição de valor da constante

Tags: javascript, node.js, requisição

Estou tentando criar uma função pra cadastro de usuários, mas tem uma constante que não está atribuindo o valor da requisição, segue o código que tenho atualmente:

**Services**

```
async create(req, res) {
    const user = req.body
    user.id8 = parseInt(user.id8)
    //Search for the passed 8ID in database
    const userID = await User.findOne({ id8: user.id8 })
    //Search for the passed Email in database
    const userMail = await User.findOne({ email: user.email })
    //8ID not exists in database
    if (!userID) {
        //Email not exists in databse
        if (!userMail) {
            User.create(user)
                .then(() => {
                    return res.status(201)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal error: ", err })
                })
        } else {
            return res.status(409).json({ error: `Email já cadastrado no sistema` })
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(409).json({ error: `8ID ja cadastrado no sistema` })
    }
},
```

**Controller**

```
async create(req, res) {
    const user = req.body

    if (userVal.isValid(user)) {
        const userCreate = await userServ.create(user)
        userCreate.status === 200
            ? res.status(200)
            : res.status(400).json({ error: "Os dados passados são inválidos" })
    } else {
        return res.status().json({ error: "Dados inválidos" })
    }
},
```

A `const user` no controller contém um objeto com as informações preenchidas no cadastro de usuario, como nome, senha, email e 8ID (não é chave primaria mas é único).

Após a validação do tipo dos dados, eles são enviados para uma função `create` no services. O objeto é recebido na requisição do services, mas ao tentar atribuir o objeto à uma nova `const user`, o mesmo não acontece, `user` permanece como `undefined`.

Tentei utilizar `let` e outros nomes pra variável no service mas continuou com o mesmo erro. Já consultei pelo debug as informações recebidas na request do services e o objeto está inteiramente ali, mas a `const` não atribui este valor.

Comment: [Não poste código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Dito isso. não seria `const { user } = req.body;`?  Não dá pra saber com base no código compartilhado

Comment: coloquei como imagem pq uma parte tava cortando na formatação. Então, o user não é um campo da requisição, essa requisição vem com nome de usuário, email, senha, turno e cargo, os quais são dados obrigatórios pra poder cadastrar o usuario

Comment: pq criar uma constante de um valor que pode mudar cada vez que a função for invocada? acho que não entendeu bem o conceito de `const`, use uma variável comum no lugar

Comment: O valor não vai mudar, estou armazenando os dados na constante pra consultar dados do objeto passado no resto do escopo da função

Comment: Acho que agora entendi. Você está chamando o Service em `userServ.create(user)`? Se sim, você está passando um único argumento (`user`) e está tentando receber dois (`req, res`). Ao tentar acessar `req.body`, você está tentando acessar `user.body`, que é `undefined`.

Comment: Exatamente, eu testei no debug do VSCode e os dados estão circulando bem no controller, o `user` até ai está como um objeto contendo os dados passados, quando eu envio pro services através do `userServ.create(user)`, eu vejo que na requisição do services o `req` contém os dados do objeto passado, mas ao tentar atribuir esse objeto da requisição a nova `const user`, ele não recebe esses dados

Comment: É por causa do que eu disse... Você espera receber `req, res` mas passar `user`. Ou faça `userServ.create(user)` esperando receber `user`, ou faça `userServ.create(req, res)`.

Comment: Entendi, e como posso fazer pra retornar o status nesse caso?

Comment: Isso já é outra dúvida mais complexa que não cabe responder aqui. Recomendo que pesquise sobre "node express architecture" no Google e coisas do tipo para entender melhor quais são as possibilidades e ter um norte.

Comment: Entendi, mas obrigado pela ajuda @RafaelTavares, eu tava msm empacado nessa parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, eu faria assim:

**Controller:**

```
async create(req, res) {
    const user = req.body

    if (!userVal.isValid(user)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Dados inválidos" });
    }

    
    const userCreated = await userServ.create(user);

    if (!userCreated.success) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: userCreated.message });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: userCreated.message });
}
```

Service:

```
async create(user) {
    const id8 = parseInt(user.id8);
    const userID = await User.findOne({ id8 });

    if (userID) {
        return { success: false, message: "8ID ja cadastrado no sistema" };
    }

    const userMail = await User.findOne({ email: user.email });


    if (userMail) {
        return { success: false, message: "Email já cadastrado no sistema" };
    }

    await User.create(user);

    return { success: true, message: "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso" };
},
```

Comment: Testei e funcionou perfeitamente, eu não sabia que podia fazer um return assim no services, mt obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: boa, bom saber que funcionou certiho. Boa sorte!